# Recovering Oracle SSH Keys using SSH

Tags: ssh, 22.04

I'm running an Oracle server on Ubuntu 22.04.

I've lost my SSH keys though I still have SSH access because I've logged in before I lost my keys.

How can I recover my private key and public key?

Comment: I assume you meant "oracle cloud server instance"? see `~/.ssh/authorized_keys ` on the server. You only get the private key from the server and need to make a new public key iirc.

Comment: in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys its not that very long it stats with ssh-rsa and ends in ssh-key-2022-07-15 is the entire content of the file my private key?

Comment: The authorized_keys file on the *remote* side contains your *public* key(s) - the private key stays on your *local* machine, and can't be re-created from the public key for obvious security reasons. Your best option is probably to create a new key pair.